# Vigenere vs triple vigenere, which one it’s better?

Tags: encryption, key, vigenere

I’m doing some research about Vigenere cipher.
I want to ask you 2 main questions that I found very hard to answer.
Let’s say we have plaintext that is encoded 3 times with 3 different keys each time. Would it be more secure than using the usual vigenere with a single encryption?
In the context of the answer to the question above, does it matter if the length of the three keys was different?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Vigenere vs triple vigenere, which one it’s better?"* Surely triple vigenere is three times as good? ;-)

Comment: This is really a question asking for crypto advice, and thus is off-topic for stackoverflow. Please take the time to read through the help section on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as other topics in [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Off-topic, but if you perform Vigenère encryption using multiple keys of equal length, the result will be equivalent to enciphering just once with a single key of the same length as the three different keys. If you use keys of different lengths, then the result will be equivalent to enciphering with a key whose length is the least common multiple of the lengths of the separate keys. If these separate keys have no common factors, then the equivalent key length is the product of their lengths, which could be quite long. So, yes, under some circumstances, triple Vigenère is a bit harder to break.